# Is there a recommended way to upgrade from 20.10 to 22.04?

Tags: upgrade, 20.10, 22.04

I'd like to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.10 to 22.04 but get messages like

> An upgrade from 'groovy' to 'impish' is not supported with this tool.

or

> Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.

following documentation and blogs I have found so far (all require the starting point to be 20.04 or 21.10), eg [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish) otherwise comprehensive tip .

What are the least disruptive options?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 has reached the end of it's life. It will be easier to back up your files and do a clean install.

Comment: There is no tested, supported path directly from 20.10 to 22.04. Also, a 20.10 system has not received any security updates in 9 months, so it perhaps shouldn't be networked regularly anymore. The *safest* and *simplest* path for most users is to backup your data and then to clean-install 22.04. Since we don't know your skills, it's hard to estimate what you might consider *disruptive*.

Comment: Your only upgrade path is 20.10 -> 21.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04, however all those interim releases are end of life as well.  Unfortunately, it would be faster and better for you to backup your data you want to keep to external media, and then cleanly install 22.04.  The upgrade process between all the interim releases increases the chance of significant failures or problems being introduced substantially.

Comment: *(For other readers, FWIW: 20.04 to 22.04 will be possible as they both are "LTS", expect to be notified; it will happen as 22.04.1 appears)*

Comment: This is why I keep `/home` on a seperate partition. I can do a full install/Something Else, and uncheck the "Format" box for `/home`. I keep a history of system changes I've made in `/home`, to help me bend the system to my will, or the other way. I also have a system backup process.

Comment: The recommend way is to re-install.  If you're using a desktop system, you can re-install without loss of data files, your *manually installed* packages will get re-installed automatically (*if available for the new release in Ubuntu repositories*) and I did it myself when 20.10 reached EOL as I keep a system running on each supported release; and already had a 21.04 thus it was 21.10 I went to. My music was untouched, my non-default music player gets re-installed etc.. But you didn't specify if desktop/server; and *clean* re-install is recommended.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades