# Is there a recommended way to upgrade from 20.10 to 22.04.1?

Tags: upgrade, ssh, 22.04, 20.10

This is sort of a duplicate of a question from a month ago (e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1404281/1603295)).

In the comments of that post Hannu said:

> (For other readers, FWIW: 20.04 to 22.04 will be possible as they both are "LTS", expect to be notified; it will happen as 22.04.1 appears)

How would I upgrade/update from 20.10 to 22.04? I'm running this on a Vultr server which I SSH into and I'm a bit of a Linux noob so I'm not sure how |I would go about doing a clean install using SSH command line

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: You are right: this is a duplicate question, so it should be closed. The answers indicate you only can upgrade from one version to the next (e.g. 21.10 to 22.04) or from one long term release to the next (e.g. 20.04 to 22.04).

Comment: You can upgrade from a LTS release to the next non-LTS (ie. 20.04 can currently jump to 21.10), or from one LTS to the next LTS (20.04 can also go to 22.04), but from a non-LTS the upgrade path is to the next release only (no skipping).  That is current practice of the [Ubuntu Release Upgrader tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) ie. 20.10 requires a re-install for a *supported* upgrade.  You can re-install desktop systems without losing data files, having your *manually installed* files auto-re-installed (if packages available in Ubuntu repositories)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 was the 2020-October release (ie. *year.month* format is used; 2000 added to year), so you can easily add 9 months (*supported life*) and know when the EOL will be reached allowing easy planning, even without seeing warning or [20.10 EOL notices](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/).. but the upgrade path was gone the moment [19.04 reached EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) as the Ubuntu release upgrader tool won't upgrade to EOL products.