# Trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS apt (>= 2.1.10ubuntu0.3)

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, dependencies, 20.10

When upgrading from 20.10 to 22.04.3 LTS
get message: Required Depends not installed
the required dependency 'apt(>=2.1.10ubuntu0.3)'is not installed

```
PC:~$ sudo apt install apt 2.1.10ubuntu0.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 2.1.10ubuntu0.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '2.1.10ubuntu0.3'
```

Comment: There is no supported release-upgrade path from 20.10 to 22.04, so it's unclear what you did. There used to be a path 20.10 to 21.04 to 21.10 to 22.04, but that path closed when the intermediate releases reached End Of Standard Support. Consider backing up your data and doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04. It's likely to be the fastest and easiest way to get you there.

Comment: Okay that sounds logical I will try it. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to run the 'do-release-upgrade' script a couple times (20.10 -> 21.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04). This would be pretty time consuming, backing up and installing the latest release might be the best option.

[Is there a recommended way to upgrade from 20.10 to 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404281/is-there-a-recommended-way-to-upgrade-from-20-10-to-22-04)